# Coin flip in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently taking an introduction to java class in college and this particular assignment has me stumped. The goal is to “simulate flipping a coin (0 is heads and 1 is tails) 5 times. For each flip, the user guesses the status of the flip. The computer reports if the status and evaluates the guess after each flip and provides a cumulative report before termination.” It also states “Using a Random object seeded with a user-defined input, generate a 0 or 1 for the coin toss.”

So far the code that I have takes the inputted seed and randomizes a number between 0 and 1 after the user guesses which it’ll be. But it looks so messy and repetitive. How can I simplify this?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
System.out.println("Enter the seed for the Random object.");
int seed = scanner.nextInt(); //Saves input as seed

Random coin = new Random(seed);
int guess = coin.nextInt(2);

System.out.println("What is your guess for trial # 1?");
int trialOne = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess +".");

if (guess == trialOne) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
}

Random coin2 = new Random(seed);
int guess2 = coin2.nextInt(2);

System.out.println("What is your guess for trial # 2?");
int trialTwo = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess +".");

if (guess == trialTwo) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
}

Random coin3 = new Random(seed);
int guess3 = coin3.nextInt(2);

System.out.println("What is your guess for trial # 3?");
int trialThree = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess +".");

if (guess == trialThree) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
}

Random coin4 = new Random(seed);
int guess4 = coin4.nextInt(2);

System.out.println("What is your guess for trial # 4?");
int trialFour = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess4 +".");

if (guess == trialFour) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
}

Random coin5 = new Random(seed);
int guess5 = coin5.nextInt(2);

System.out.println("What is your guess for trial # 5?");
int trialFive = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess5 +".");

if (guess == trialFive) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
}
```

Comment: Study about looping: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: You definitely want to eliminate the 5 copies of very similar code.  You should place one copy inside a loop that loops 5 times.  To remember each `guess` and `trial`, you should have two lists that you push those onto..so like `guesses` and `trials`.  At the end, those lists will both have 5 elements in them.   Your loop should involve an index, so that the first time through, the index is `1`, then second time it's `2`.  You can use that index to print out a string with the trial number in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a for-loop to simplify the code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
System.out.println("Enter the seed for the Random object.");
int seed = scanner.nextInt(); //Saves input as seed
Random coin = new Random(seed);

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    int guess = coin.nextInt(2);

    System.out.println("What is your guess for trial #" + i + "?");
    int trial = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess + ".");

    if (guess == trial) {
        System.out.println("You guessed right!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
    }
}
```

You were doing repetitive task, which followed the same pattern. So, you can easily simplify such code using loop. You can visit [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to learn in details about how the `for` statement works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code better, you'll need to use a function. So basically, put this code.

```
    Random coin2 = new Random(seed);
        int guess2 = coin2.nextInt(2);
    
        System.out.println("What is your guess for trial # 2?");
        int trialTwo = scanner.nextInt();
    
        System.out.println("The coin toss was a " + guess +".");
    
        if (guess == trialTwo) {
            System.out.println("You guessed right!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, try again next time!");
        }
```

Into this function. The idea being, you're re-using this code, rather than typing it out over and over again.

```
private static void getUserGuessForTrial(int trial) {

}
```